# How to allow the service to install without prompting for the User ID, Password, Confirm Password

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

when I try to install the service (installutil service.exe) from Visual Studio command Prompt, it prompts to set User ID, Password to install the service. You can refer to the screenshot(link) of credential prompt.

[picture of prompting for credentials while installing service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VVG1.png)

This was done in C#.net with .NET 4.0 framework.

I have searched for this prior posting this question and end-up setting the credentials to null (please refer to the code pasted below). But it didn't work.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.StockManagementInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // StockManagementProcessInstaller1
        // 
        this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
        this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
        // 
        // StockManagementInstaller1
        // 
        this.StockManagementInstaller1.DisplayName = "StockManagement";
        this.StockManagementInstaller1.ServiceName = "StockManagement";
        this.StockManagementInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1,
        this.StockManagementInstaller1});

    }
```

Can anyone help me how to get rid of this and install the service without any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install your service as local service without a password prompt , just do the following:

```
// StockManagementProcessInstaller1
// 
this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService;
this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
```

Instead of:

```
// StockManagementProcessInstaller1
// 
this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
this.StockManagementProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
```

I hope that support your question.

Comment: Hi @DeJaVo
what should I replace "ServiceAccount" with.

sorry for troubling, I am to service.

Comment: Sorry, got it !...
included namespace

Comment: Thanks !
My service is running ...
Thanks @DeJaVo ..
Sorry I can't Upvote your answer and mark as "Answer" as I don't have required Reputation.


Thanks Alot again...

Cheers ... :)

Comment: Actually you can mark as solution with your reputation. 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work please kindly consider to accept my solution

Comment: Thanks DoJoVo ... I have upvoted it, but it doesn't display a green tick, instead it is showing a grey tick

Comment: I only have 11 rep.
Getting the same notification(I need 15 rep to make my vote visible)

Comment: I think you can vote up and mark as solution now, since you have 16 rep.